# Doing a really simple circular "graph" in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I know there are already answers on TeX SE on how to draw a circular graph in latex. Even thought, I wasn't able to adapt these answers into my simple case
, so if anyone could help me with this one I'd be really appreciated.

I want to have the following circular graph:

[image]

I imagine this is pretty simple to do (I am new into drawing in latex). Ideally, I would like to have no circles around the letters.

Comment: If you already found some asnwers for this, show us what you've got ([minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) and where the problem is. See e.g. [How can I draw a circular graph in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278216/123129).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `graphs` library that comes with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[clockwise, n=3, V={i, j, k}, edge={bend left=45, -stealth}] { subgraph C_n };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]